# ADB accessing shell /data/data/com.<specified_app>

Tags: adb, permissions

I tried this ADB command:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.whatsapp
```

I want retrieve Whatsapp key file without root but I still get permission denied. Any idea how can I get read access of `com.whatsapp` directory?

Comment: You need a rooted phone. Then you can execute `su`  and you will be able to access all directories within `/data/data/`

Comment: you can uninstall WhatsApp with special adb flag so the app data remains on phone. after reboot, you can downgrade to older WhatsApp version that allows adb backup without root. there used to be a script for doing these steps automatized. read over [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-whatsapp-key-db-extractor-crypt6-12-non-root-updated-october-2016.2770982/page-37). another post suggest the key itself is **hidden in `.nomedia` file** (cannot proof that I don't have WhatsApp)

Answer (score 0):

Yea sadly the /data/data folders are only accessible with root... you might be able to use a virtual root android to do this but wouldn't hold my breath... (requires pc)

Comment: To the moderator that declined my flag, do you seriously think that this should not be a comment.  There is no concrete answer here - its speculation.